# Is there a Swing library for Windows style progress bars?

Tags: windows, open-source, library, java

If I create progress bar using C# and Windows Forms, it has shading that gives it a 3D look as well a semi-transparent white animation that moves from the left to the right:

[image: progress bar]

Is there any library that allows me to create a Windows-style animated progress bar in Java (using Swing)?

Answer (score 0):

I think when you want to stick to Swing only you need to style the progress bar for yourself.

But if you actually mean that you want an UI library for Java that supports your shown Windows 7(?) style progress bar, one option is to use [Eclipse's SWT](https://wiki.eclipse.org/SWT).

Check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18744145/progress-bar-does-not-update-immediately) on StackOverflow which gives the following image that looks alot like the one you have given:

[image: SWT Application]

The question gives also some sample Java code that can kickstart your experiments.